# Geth SWARM no peers found!

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, geth-debugging, peers, swarm

Synced via Geth lightnode to latest block --cache=2048. (7200RPM HDD with 8GB RAM)

Then created new geth account and did swarm --bzzaccount $BZZ

I'm am able to only browse localhost, upload to local but not download (404 error). Same error with testnet.

I've also added enodes from swarm-gateway.net to admin.addpeers but still cannot connect. It shows as 40 peers connected but I'm still getting these errors.

Some of the logs are below without stopping the connection.

```
INFO [04-20|19:01:16.740] unable to request                        request addr=1ae4776c80028cd48884f1a4875ce36f8eb3cd9423c459cc2376a78b065e7861 err="no peer found"

INFO [04-20|19:01:20.144] unable to request                        request addr=0f68b0450c97f77f8fe77899b86263dad6f0a55fbe6f6ae10cd11732c752dd04 err="no peer found"

ERROR[04-20|18:52:10.296] Message send error, dropping peer        peer=a2239c59643d0256 err="write tcp 192.168.0.25:49187->52.232.7.187:30405: i/o timeout"

ERROR[04-20|19:06:27.949] peer.handleIncoming                      err="Message handler error: (msg code 1): client params 'SYNC|0|h' not provided to peer b4669fadcedad677b2b810c9b91aaa9a94e61d9fc8e2165cb0c93401c1a3002e"
```

Been running for 2 hours so far.

Comment: Please also include exactly the sequence of commands you are attempting to run.